# Why did Western democracies sign the Munich Agreement?

Tags: international-relations, europe, nazism

Why did Western democracies sign the [Munich Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Agreement) with Nazi
Germany when they knew the nature of Nazi regime? What did they want to obtain by signing this agreement?

In 1938/1939, two pacts/agreements shocked the world and disappointed many European countries:

1. the [Munich Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munich_Agreement) with Western democracies that's to say, England and France in 1938,  and;
2. [Molotov_Ribbentrop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact) non aggression pact with Stalin in 1939.

The motive of the pact with Stalin is easy to understand, because they wanted to share Eastern Europe, but I cannot understand the reason behind France's and England's concessions to Hitler. Especially when we know that this agreement was signed after the [annexation of Austria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_occupation_of_Czechoslovakia) and Hitler's expansionist ambitions were revealed.

Comment: This appears to be more of a question for historians than for experts on contemporary politics. I will migrate the question to history stack exchange.

Comment: The Munich agreement was signed *before* the occupation of the Czech border areas. In fact it was all about said occupation.

Comment: As to the motive: something between a naive hope for peace and a less benign hope that Hitler would start a war against the Soviet Union sooner or later if the Allies could avoid a war with Germany.

Comment: Germany had started low-intensity undeclared war on Czechoslovakia on 17 September 1938. and                                                                                                                                            The Munich Agreement  was an agreement concluded at Munich on 30 September 1938,

Comment: **This is a question from a new user, who may not be familiar with our [culture](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4053/faq-historystack-exchange) on H:SE. Please make an extra effort to be welcoming: phrase feedback in a positive manner and try to explain our assumptions. If possible, offer constructive advice on how to [improve the question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3224).**

Comment: Does [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appeasement) answer the question? if not, why not?

Comment: Contemporary example of the same: Why Western democracies allowed Putin regime to annex a part of Ukraine when they know the nature of Putin's regime?

Comment: I think the nature of the nazi regime was not immediately apparent to the Allies. They knew it as a totalitarian regime, but that was not so unusual at that time. The true nature of its practices became more widespread knowledge later on in the war

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Naivety vs realpolitik

First of all, don't fall into modern trap of idolizing democracy. Remember that for example [Plato consider it second worst regime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plato%27s_five_regimes), slightly better than tyranny, and actually precursor to tyranny. Also, original meaning of *demos-kratos* is simply rule of the people, not necessarily parliamentary democracy. For example, Hitler considered Third Reich as a from of direct democracy, where German Volk rules directly trough their Fuhrer. USSR of course considered itself democratic, much more then liberal bourgeois democracies of the West.

And even if you have parliamentary democracy, things are far from ideal. As we could see in modern times, much depends on who has more money, media support, support of big business and finally [who counts the votes](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/2140-those-who-vote-decide-nothing-those-who-count-the-vote). And even if you have democratic government in one country, that does not mean it is obliged to defend or spread democracy in other parts of the world. For example, US and UK gladly cooperate with Saudi Arabia and other Gulf monarchies and are enemies of much more democratic Iran.

Therefore, things in international arena are decided much more by interests and [realpolitik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realpolitik) than by some imagined ideals. Let's examine country by country:

- Britain : British longstanding policy towards continent is that it should not not allow single continental power that could unite whole of Europe against it, possibly even challenging it on high seas. In that sense, they could accept Germany as dominant in Central Europe if they block USSR and spread of communism, but not much more than that. Or, in our case, they were OK with Germany getting parts of Czechoslovakia (latter whole of Czechia and Slovakia as puppet state) . But, they could not accept demise of Poland because by then Germany would become that dominant power in Europe and British could not allow this.
- France: France was afraid of German territorial ambitions on itself (Alsace-Lorraine) , and considered that it would have very though time defending against it alone. French [leftist government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89douard_Daladier#Munich_Agreement) was against caving in to the Germans, but they could do precious little alone, plus that same government was not really popular among certain parts of French society and in French army. Therefore, they finally consented to Munich.
- Poland: Poland at that time deluded itself that Germans were lesser evil than USSR, and even dreamed about alliance with them against USSR. They also had some designs [on Czech territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Czechoslovak_War), and could be said that they participated in partition of Czechoslovakia. Anyway, they didn't want to let Soviet troops to pass trough their territory to Czechoslovakia and essentially that doomed any effort of relief.
- Soviet Union: USSR was at that time still engaged against Germany and Italy in Spain, and all of that was before Molotov-Ribbentrop pact. At that time they were willing to go to war in Czechoslovakia but they had their beef with Poland because of lost territory in Western Ukraine and Belarus in [Polish–Soviet war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish%E2%80%93Soviet_War). Therefore, they could not intervene.
- Other players: Among other smaller players in Europe, countries like Romania and Yugoslavia were not amused with what was happening, but they mostly wanted to keep status quo and privately hoped that Germans would be satisfied. Countries like Italy, Hungary and Bulgaria wanted *revanche* foe what happened in WW1 and they supported Germany. US public opinion on the other hand was mostly isolationist at the time, and wanted to leave European businesses to Europeans and to avoid another bloody war.

Overall, while today Third Reich is presented as an evil incarnate in popular media, in 1930's it was not perceived as such. Germany was just another player on international scene, certainly dangerous, but not something unheard of . And, simply saying, other countries were willing to deal with them.

Comment: The initial bit about democracy seems irrelevant to the question and conflates what countries *said* about being democratic with what their leadership actually believed. There are a few good points in here -- e.g., that people in the 30s did not see Nazi Germany as we do -- but a lot of it seems is off-topic or even incorrect.

Comment: "is presented as an evil incarnate in popular media" - are you suggesting that this description is incorrect? Afaiac, the assessment by "popular media" in this case is consistent with scientific research.

Comment: @MarkOlson Was US democracy in 1860 (slavery) ? Or in 1940 (segregation) ? Athens when they executed Socrates ?  How about UK before WW2 (no voting rights for India) ? What would future historians think about this period ( Big Tech censorship, possible voter fraud, corporate interests) ? Obviously, our current standards about democracy are not universal even in this time, not to mention any other period.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Do you consider Mongols to be evil incarnate ? Or Ottomans ? How about Soviets ? Or even US (Vietnam) ? Unfortunately, human history is a history of evil . I'm afraid that Third Reich (which undoubtedly was evil) is not exception, more like confirmation of the rule. But in 1930s they were just another actor on a world stage.

Comment: @rs.29 Exceptional for the Third Reich was the industrial complex in terms of war and the Holocaust (Total war), driven by a quasi replacement for religion, a state ideology. The modern democracy of this epoch was declared as a symptom of weakness by Hitler. Some of these aspects were already well known to the western democracies long before the attack on Poland in September 1939.

Comment: @Secundi Not necessarily. Industry was a relatively new invention (late 18th and 19th century) . But already Ottomans used industrial products to commit genocide against Armenians. Religious state ideology is of course something much older. Hitler declared parliamentarism (i.e. political parties and elections with parties) as a weakness, not democracy as itself. And parliamentarism was in crisis in lots of countries at that time.

Comment: @rs.29 In terms of industrial complex (war), I meant the extreme focus of the german economy on this aspect, never seen before world-wide this fast and intensive (the sowjets later on showed a similar intensive allocation of resources after the first shock of the german attacks but this was within the context of an ongoing war). This kind of economy was based on the premise, that war was and was required to be the final intention (in order to bypass the common economic schemes that would have forced the Third Reich into a huge econ. depression due to this extreme focus).

Comment: @Secundi Actually, it could be argued that German economy was not focused enough on war in first years. They still produced lots of consumer goods, and Hitler was afraid to rapidly plunge living standard in order to avoid rebellion like in WW1. Only after defeat at Stalingrad and Sportpalast speech German economy gradually turned into total war economy.

Comment: About France, it must be said that the French had a so bad remembrance of the four and a half years of WWI that "war at no price" was a rather common opinion, that one could qualify (maybe inexactly) by the word "defeatism".

Comment: @JeanMarieBecker French interwar history is very interesting. It could be said that after WW1 parties of the Left rose on popular anti-war sentiment, while later when Hitler rose to power they switched tune, and now Right became wary of the war .  But this of course is a gross simplification, and this topics warrants question on its own.

Comment: @rs.29 You are perfectly right. Moreover, two years before the Munich Agreement, in  1936, the "Front Populaire" government (Socialists+Communists), headed by Léon Blum, had already decided not to help (officially) Spanish Republic...  Have a look to [this document](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00374318/document)

Comment: Germany was not "just another actor" after the Rhineland and Austria, and Munich was not just another "deal". There was a line being drawn in the sand, which was crossed in March 1939 when the rump of Czechoslovakia was occupied. From that point the dealing was over, the trust was gone, and the containment process began. That paper Chamberlain waved (which we have all seen) was a signal to the British public and the world.

Comment: @AgentOrange Well, nope. Germany was just another actor, and as you pointed out Germans did breach Munich agreement when they occupied rest of Czechoslovakia and other things that had happened at the same time. Yet, there was no war in March. Why not ? Because Britain could still tolerate Germany as a strong Central European power. But once Germany moved to attack Poland, they would became dominant power in Europe. Britain could not allow that.

Comment: @rs.29 You are missing the significance of the Rhineland and Austria in alerting the British and French to the growing German threat, and you are missing the significance of the Munich Agreement in finally drawing the line in the sand which led to the Mutual Defense pacts which were signed with Poland and others after the betrayal of March 1939. These are pertinent to the question asked. There was no war in March 1939 because the political groundwork for war was still incomplete. Munich was the proof of German deceit which made the completion politically possible.

Comment: @AgentOrange What alerting :) Mein Kampf has been written for years, Hitler repeated hundreds of times that Österreich is just Eastern Reich. Germany was already engaged in Spain.  Also, Britain and France started rearmament much earlier, Britain perhaps even earlier than Germany. Poland was actually ok with destruction of Chezkoslovakia as long as they get their morsel - Cieszyn Silesia. As I said, Britain would tolerate Germany as strong Central European power, as long as they do not go further than that.

Comment: @rs.29 This is dragging out due to your obfuscation. Your answer does not explain the connection between the Munich Agreement and the subsequent development of the situation. So your answer is insufficient.

Comment: @AgentOrange It does, you would only have to read it :) Specifically for the British, they could live with strong Germany in Central Europe (even if that means occupation of Czechoslovakia) , but Germany becoming dominant in whole of Europe (by spreading trough Polish territories) was too much for them to bear.

Comment: @rs.29 I've read it. If that is as far as you can see, then so be it. Let that be your answer. There's nothing achieved by by the British and French according to your interpretation of the significance of the Munich Agreement, that could not have been achieved by them simply doing nothing at all...

Comment: @AgentOrange They achieved "peace in our time" :)  They got the promise that Germany would not go further, and a way to negate defense pact that France had with Czechoslovakia.  Face saving measure for France, and way for Britain to avoid war because of France .

Comment: @AgentOrange Btw, without agreement French could potentially decide to honor their agreement with Czechoslovakia (although unprepared to do so) , and that would leave Britain in difficult spot - let France be defeated and Germany be dominant power in continent, or join the war and potentially let USSR benefit by letting its adversaries to bleed themselves dry.

Answer (score 6):

The agreement was the climax of the **appeasement politics** of Britain and France. The core intention was clear: Avoid a war as far as possible, even if bad compromises are required.

Further on: The Munich Agreement was about the [Sudetenland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudetenland#Sudeten_Crisis) crisis and was declared as some internal German territory related issue (see historical background of Sudeten Germans). So there was a somehow not totally irrelevant entangled component persistent to this crisis in terms of ethnics. In order to stay consistent to former similar decisions like the appeasement to the annexation of Austria, they granted access for Hitler here again.

Comment: Good answer; it would be a better answer if it had sources/references.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace , thanks for the edit! I'm new to this stackexchange and was not sure, if linking the wiki is the right way. Besides the core article about the agreement, I think the background of the Sudetenland / Bohemia should complete the picture.

Comment: references are _always_ good; history is about sources like physics is about units.

Comment: French were not that much into appeasement, but they didn't have much choice.

Comment: @rs.29 That's right. The influence of Britain and Italy (Mussolini...) was too strong. Besides that, there were well known further territorial intentions of Poland (not part of the contract though) with focus on Czechoslovakia for instance.

Answer (score 1):

There were a number of factors:

**Hitler's demands seemed somewhat legitimate.** Hitler demanded that those areas of Bohemia and Moravia that had a German-speaking majority population join with Germany, after a referendum. The principle that areas with a population majority of nationality X would become part of country X had been applied in the opposite direction to German border areas [with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_East_Prussian_plebiscite) [Poland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_Silesia_plebiscite), [Denmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1920_Schleswig_plebiscites) and [Belgium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eupen-Malmedy) after WWI, so Hitler's demand that this principle be applied to Czech border areas did not seem entirely unreasonable.

**Chamberlain expected Hitler to play by the rules.** Hitler had promised to leave the rest of Czechoslovakia alone and Chamberlain seems to have believed him. See his (in)famous remarks re. "[peace for our time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peace_for_our_time)". In real life the Germans occupied the rest of Bohemia and Moravia a mere six months later, on March 15th 1939.

**Neither France nor Britain were really ready to go to war over Czechoslovakia.** The population of both countries still remembered WWI (as did the Germans btw) and were not really keen on repeating the experience.

**The British were wilfully ignorant of important details.** Chamberlain famously spoke of [a "quarrel in a far away country, between people of whom we know nothing"](https://www.bbc.co.uk/archive/chamberlain-addresses-the-nation-on-his-negotiations-for-peace/zjrjgwx). This was a widespread attitude in Britain at the time. In such an atmosphere it is easy to overlook that Czechoslovakia would lose its [equivalent of the Maginot line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Czechoslovak_border_fortifications) or that [the German-speaking minority in Germany's ally Italy had it much worse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italianization_of_South_Tyrol) than the German minority in Czechoslovakia.

---

There were also allegations that the British conservatives hoped to be able to use Hitler to check Stalin, in an echo of what [German conservatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_von_Papen) had hoped to accomplish in 1933. Not really sure how much of an influence that was in Munich.

Answer (score 0):

Until the annexation of Czechoslovakia, German expansionism had the "fig leaf" of claiming only to unite all German-speaking people into one country.

This was apparently the case with Austria, whose name Osterreich means "eastern kingdom" in Germany. The claim was that Austria, who was occupied elsewhere, had been left out of German unification in 1871, and the so-called Anschluss was made only to rectify all of this oversight.

With regard to Czechoslovakia, Hitler's initial claim was that he only wanted the mountainous [Sudetenland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudetenland), where most of Czechoslovakia's 3.5 million Germans (one quarter of the country's population) lived. Of course, the lie was given to this claim when Hitler annexed non-German parts of the Sudetenland (the most defendible parts of Czechoslovakia in 1938, then all of what we later called the Czech Republic in 1939.

Comment: This is a somewhat minor point, but I think your description of how Austria and Germany ended up in two different countries is misleading. And you are ignoring attempts to unite the two after WWI, which were thwarted by the Allies.

Comment: And your post reads as if Czech was occupied in three steps. First Sudetenland, then the most defensible parts, then the rest. In fact, the so-called Sudetenland *was* the most defensible part and also were the border fortifications were located.